# How to output a BlobProperty from my model to a hex string

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blob

I have this class representing my model :

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class PuzzleSets(db.Model):
   img = db.BlobProperty(required=True)
   ...
```

and I want to retrieve that blobproperty. However, I want to retrieve the bytes array and output it to a string. Ex. : "AE214FAA21617772" for a 8 bytes image stored in my blob.

I tried with a blob_reader and some other methods but I always get errors like

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

or

hex() argument can't be converted to hex

and such

Anyone can help me get the correct way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got what I wanted with this sleek line of code :

```
self.response.out.write(''.join([hex(z)[2:].zfill(2) for z in bytearray(puzzleset_instance.img)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Blobreader is for reading from the BlobStore.
To use the BlobProperty / get a string use:

```
data = db.Blob(puzzleset_instance.img)
```

If your blob contains text, use :

```
unicode_data = db.Blob(instance.blob_property).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: all right, this gives me a blob object, how can I output a hex string representing the bytes from that?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode a str instance in hex with `foo.encode('hex')`.